# Pix2pix program terminates after giving Thread warning of Tensorflow

Tags: tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, generative-adversarial-network

I am trying to run https://github.com/eriklindernoren/Keras-GAN/blob/master/pix2pix/pix2pix.py

```
python pix2pix.py
```

Execution terminates giving following message

```
Using TensorFlow backend.
WARNING:tensorflow:From C:\Users\kulkarni\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\op_def_library.py:263: colocate_with (from tensorflow.python.framework.ops) is deprecated and will be removed in a future version.
Instructions for updating:
Colocations handled automatically by placer.
2019-05-29 14:43:23.767965: I tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:141] Your CPU supports instructions that this TensorFlow binary was not compiled to use: AVX AVX2
2019-05-29 14:43:23.770965: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/process_util.cc:71] Creating new thread pool with default inter op setting: 4. Tune using inter_op_parallelism_threads for best performance.
```

Tried following solution given at [Why Keras model on "bare" CPU is faster?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52883145/why-keras-model-on-bare-cpu-is-faster) but no luck.

I am running this on Windows 7 Intel i3 CPU 64-bit machine.

How to do proper settings to get the code running?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not throwing any error. So I'm guessing the script isn't finding the training dataset. Try downloading the dataset and try running it again.

```
bash download_dataset.sh facades
python pix2pix.py
```

Comment: Thanks!! Your guess was right. Although data file was there, it was not untarred. Once I did it, the execution moved on.